# GenerationType.SEQUENCE generating negative primary keys

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am seeing an interesting behavior that I cannot explain. For some reason the configuration below is causing the first batch of primary keys to be generated in negative range (starting with -28). My hibernate version is 5.2.14 and my database is Postgres 9.6.11. The initial sequence of keys consistently generated in all environments are:
`-28 -27 -26 -25 -8 -7 1 2 52 53`

I have reached out to Postgres developer mailing list and they think it is Hibernate (and not Postgres generating the negative numbers)

```
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS my_schema.my_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.my_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  NO MAXVALUE
  START 1
  CACHE 20;
```

My primary key hibernate mapping is as shown below:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "MY_ID_COLUMN")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "MY_SEQ",
                strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1,
                   name = "MY_SEQ",
                   sequenceName = "MY_SEQ",
                   schema = "MY_SCHEMA")
private Long myPkId;
```

We are using hibernate from a spring-boot project and is configured as a JPA provider in spring-data. The configuration is shown below:

```
spring:
  data:
    jpa:
      repositories:
        bootstrap-mode: lazy
  cache:
    jcache:
      config: classpath:ehcache.xml
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgres://..
    username: **********
    password: **********
    hikari:
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      maximum-pool-size: 25
      connection-init-sql: select 1
      minimum-idle: 6
      leak-detection-threshold: 95000
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    properties:
      javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode: ENABLE_SELECTIVE
      hibernate:
        cache:
          use_second_level_cache: true
          use_query_cache: true
          region:
            factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory
        javax:
          cache:
            provider: org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider
            uri: classpath:ehcache.xml
        format_sql: true
        session_factory:
          interceptor: com.abc.Interceptor
      org:
        hibernate:
          envers:
            store_data_at_delete: true
            audit_table_suffix: _HS
            revision_field_name: RVSN_ID
            revision_type_field_name: RVSN_TYPE
            use_revision_entity_with_native_id: false
      jadira:
        usertype:
          autoRegisterUserTypes: true
          databaseZone: jvm
          javaZone: jvm
    open-in-view: false
```

Comment: Could you please provide your hibernate config.

Comment: @SternK I have added the config to original post.